# Casting string to int i.e. the string "res"

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

I have a column in a table which is type `array<string>`. The table is partitioned daily since `2018-01-01`. At some stage, the values in the array goes from strings to integers. The data looks like this:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | h_id  | p_id | con           |
|------------|-------|------|---------------|
| 2018-10-01 | 52988 | 1    | ["res", "av"] |
| 2018-10-02 | 52988 | 1    | ["1","2"]     |
| 2018-10-03 | 52988 | 1    | ["1","2"]     |
```

There is a mapping between the strings and integers. "res" maps to 1 and "av" maps to 2 etc. However, I've written a query to perform some logic. Here is a snippet (subquery) of it:

```
SELECT
    t.yyyy_mm_dd,
    t.h_id,
    t.p_id,
    CAST(e.con AS INT) AS api
FROM
    my_table t
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(con) e AS con
```

My problem is that this doesn't work for the earlier dates when strings were used instead of integers. Is there anyway to select con and remap the strings to integers so the data is across all partitions?

Expected output:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | h_id  | p_id | con           |
|------------|-------|------|---------------|
| 2018-10-01 | 52988 | 1    | ["1","2"]     |
| 2018-10-02 | 52988 | 1    | ["1","2"]     |
| 2018-10-03 | 52988 | 1    | ["1","2"]     |
```

Once the values selected are all integers (within a string array), then the `CAST(e.con AS INT)` will work

**Edit:** To clarify, I will put the solution as a subquery before I use `lateral view explode`. This way I am exploding on a table where all partitions have integers in `con`. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: "res" maps to 1 and "res" maps to two etc. ??? do you need res to 1 av and to 2 ? etc means what? How to know what is what?

Comment: that should be "res maps to 1 and av maps to 2 etc". Corrected now

Comment: use IsNumeric function. I.e. CASE WHEN IsNumeric(e.con) THEN cast ELSE convert END

Comment: can't you replace the strings to numbers in a derived column

Comment: possibly, that's my question :)

Comment: please provide some scripts to insert data to my_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAST(e.api as INT)` returns NULL if not possible to cast. collect_list will collect an array including duplicates and without NULLs. If you need array without duplicated elements, use collect_set().

```
SELECT
    t.yyyy_mm_dd,
    t.h_id,
    t.p_id,
    collect_list(--array of integers 
                 --cast case as string if you need array of strings
                CASE WHEN e.api  = 'res' THEN 1   
                     WHEN e.api  = 'av'  THEN 2  
                     --add more cases   
                     ELSE CAST(e.api as INT)
                 END
                ) as con
FROM
    my_table t
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(con) e AS api
GROUP BY t.yyyy_mm_dd, t.h_id, t.p_id
```